# Can you put a <table> inside of a <div>?

Tags: html

```
<div>
    <table>
        <p>code</p>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Like the code above?**

Comment: Sure you can. Go nuts.

Comment: There’s a simple way to find out: go to the [HTML5 validator](https://html5.validator.nu/), paste your code there and you’ll see the result. `table`s in `div`s are valid, however `p`s as direct descendants of `table`s are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can put `table` tag inside `div tag`. It's 100% valid.